# trying to avoid a particular page in google plus Oauth login process

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-plus

I have a Google Plus Login setup using OAuth. I basically have a project created in the Google API console.So, when a user clicks on "Google Plus" Icon, it first take the user to the following page(Please see the image below):

[image]

**What I am looking for:**

I don't want user to see the above page, instead I just want them to enter their login credentials and finish their login procedure. Is there a way I can avoid taking them to the above page? Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

No. Users must click on a link authorizing access to their information via the application.

Comment: There is no "authorizing access" step encountered like Twitter and Facebook. As soon as user enter his email and password in the Login window, he is directed to the next window (which is shown above).

Comment: The picture you have above is the authorize access step.